# SSIS Package Metadata

Tags: sql-server, database, ssis

can I extract metadata from ssis package contains which tables or databases using to build Datawarehouse?
I want to extract lineage of database, which columns generated by which tables and columns.

I try using C# code, which is in Microsoft documentation, but I can't get what I want.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/ssis-quickstart-run-dotnet?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how clever somebody was.

You can inspect all the packages for all the Dataflow tasks and then look at sources and destinations in there and for the vast majority of people, that'll work.

Then you start to hit the "fun" corner cases. For example, a destination can use a Variable to define the table. And if they copy pasted the data flow, the "name" in the table might not match what is in the variable. So your original pattern now needs to factor in the value in the OLE DB Destination's ... table model thing (Fast load, Fast load from variable, table name, table name fast load)

Now you've got a pattern where you can figure out the destination table name whether it's hardcoded or from a variable. But what if you're blessed with a world where the table names have the environment added onto them? So now you have an Execute SQL Task (or similar) that queries some source to determine the SALES table in this environment is SALES_PROD. Which is then assigned to our Variables which is then used in the destination. Except the *design time* properties are going to be whatever the last developer had set, usually SALES_DEV, because the package must past validation.

If you want to deal with other complexities, what if your source data is not a table but a query? Now you need to be able to parse the SQL (and again, it can be dynamic) to get the referenced objects.

Oh and then Execute SQL Tasks, don't forget those.

While all of the above dynamic stuff is going to remain true for "how I would do it,"

1. get [BimlExpress](https://www.varigence.com/BimlExpress/)
2. Reverse engineer all the packages to Biml
3. Use the Biml Object model to navigate the packages extracting source and destinations.

The biggest reason why is "no COM" involved. The Data Flow task is quite challenging to work with, especially when you're casting it about various types trying to figure out what is in there.